# .lg Language Generation combined with Markdown

Tags: botframework

When using the new .lg files in my bot, how am I supposed to create a markdown link?
Since the syntax is used for something else as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/language-generation/docs/lg-file-format.md#importing-external-references), when I am using standard markdown like this:

```
Diese findest du [hier](https://google.com).
```

I am getting the error:

```
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.TemplateEngine.AddFiles(IEnumerable`1 filePaths, ImportResolverDelegate importResolver)
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: [Error] line 11:0 - line 11:199: source: /Users/x/Documents/source/x-bot/x/Responses/MainResponses.lg. error message: hier does not have an evaluator, it's not a built-in function or a customized function in template reference `hier`
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.TemplateEngine.RunStaticCheck(List`1 templates)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Responses.LocaleTemplateEngineManager..ctor(Dictionary`2 localeLGFiles, String fallbackLocale)
   at x.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /Users/x/Documents/source/x-bot/x/Startup.cs:line 133
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<BuildStartupServicesFilterPipeline>g__RunPipeline|0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ConfigureServices>g__ConfigureServicesWithContainerConfiguration|0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at x.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /Users/x/Documents/source/x-bot/x/Program.cs:line 15
   at x(String[] args) in /Users/x/Documents/source/x-bot/x/Program.cs:line 11
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Are you doing this in Composer? What's the lg statement that's generating the error?

Comment: I update my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

````
# Where do I find some code?
-```
Follow This [Link](https://github.com/)
```
````